# Noninteractive upgrade from debian10 to debian 11 return error from

Tags: python, subprocess, debian, apt, dpkg

I have several machines running Debian10 which I want to upgrade to Debian11 using a python script triggered to run from remote. The machines have packages like 'apt, sudo , grep' prompting different questions during upgrade. To remove all questions I added params:
 `-o DPkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confold"`
The problem when I run the following command in bash:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confold" -y
```

the upgrade succeeds.
When I ran it through python:

```
def create_noninteractive_environ():
    import os
    d = dict(os.environ)
    d['DEBIAN_FRONTEND'] = 'noninteractive'
    return d
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['apt', 'upgrade', '--without-new-pkgs', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::="--force-confdef"', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::="--force-confold"', '-y'], timeout=1200,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=create_noninteractive_environ()).decode()
```

I receive an error from dpkg:
`dpkg: error: need an action option` 
What is the difference in running these two commands?

Debian version: 10.13 (upgrading to 11.6)
Python version - 3.7.3
In both cases run by root

Expected - subprocess.check_output runs successfully
Actual result - returned non-zero exit status 100

Comment: When you use a shell, it parses and removes any quotes in the command line. Here, you are not using a shell, so you need to correspondingly remove the quotes in the `DPkg::Options` strings.

Comment: Yes, without quotes it worked! What was confusing that when I checked the running processes - both commands looked the same and without quotes.